# In a Windows forms application, how can I use a listbox in a DataGridView coloumn instead of a combobox

Tags: winforms, datagridview, listbox

I'm working on a windows forms application that uses a DataGridView. Some of the cells contain a DataGridViewComboBox. In some cases, I have several values to display in the combobox. For that scenario, it would be better to use a ListBox instead of a ComboBox.
Is it possible to use a multi-column listbox within a DataGridView instead of a ComboBox?
If so, can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks much.

Al D.

Answer (score 0):

Would the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Class work for your use case?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx

If not, then only other option that I'm aware of is to subclass the ComboBox and paint it yourself.